# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\;n\;4^n\;x^n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

If one applies the Ratio Test for the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\;n\;4^n\;x^n$$
gets that
$$\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|=4|x|\frac{n+1}{n}\to 4|x|.$$
Then, the above limit is less than $1$ iff
$$|x|<1/4.$$
One can also check that at $x=\pm\frac{1}{4}$ the series diverges, and therefore the interval of convergence is $(-1/4,1/4)$.

If instead one follows the definition of radius of convergence, since the sequence
$$\lbrace\left|(-1)^n\;n\;4^n\right|^{\frac{1}{n}}\rbrace$$
is bounded, then one computes
$$\lim\sup\left|(-1)^n\;n\;4^n\right|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim\sup 4\;n^{\frac{1}{n}}=4\;e^{\frac{1}{e}},$$
since $\sup n^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$. Hence, the radius of convergence of the series is
$$R=\frac{1}{4\;e^{\frac{1}{e}}}.$$
This is contradictory since $\frac{1}{4\;e^{\frac{1}{e}}}<\frac{1}{4}$.

Can anyone spot where I'm making a mistake or being sloppy?

Comment: Hint: You got the $\sup$ of $n^{1/n}$, but is that the $\color{red}{\limsup}$?

Comment: Your lim sup evaluation is incorrect. $ \limsup _{n\to \infty }x_{n}:=\inf _{n\geq 0}\,\sup _{m\geq n}x_{m}=\inf\{\,\sup\{\,x_{m}:m\geq n\,\}:n\geq 0\,\}$.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.